# Using only pointer arithmetic to traverse a loaded DLL/EXE for the PE File Format

Tags: c++, windows, pointer-arithmetic, portable-executable

My end-goal was getting the list of DLL names from the static import data table.

I thought I could do something like,
`auto data_dirs = p_loaded_image->FileHeader->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory;`

And then somehow iterate over that list of addresses and then get the DLL names that way; something like that.

So for baby-steps I was just trying to verify that I could match values for `p_loaded_image->FileHeader->OptionalHeader.SizeOfStackCommit;` against a manual pointer-math equivalent. I can't seem to do this without `Access Violation` exceptions, which seems to verify that I'm doing this incorrectly.

What did I do wrong, and how *specifically* do I get my pointer-math query to match the actual loaded image's API return for getting the same value of `SizeOfStackCommit`? If you can teach me that much, I can hopefully progress from this current point of my DLL-name-finding WIP.

For time-saving purposes, if your compiler supports `std::experimental::filesystem` you can start at the comment of `// Skip to here` to avoid all the console and file verification boilerplate, otherwise you'll need to stub it out or change it to something more friendly for older C++ specifications.

```
#include "Windows.h"
#include "Imagehlp.h"
#include "tchar.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <experimental\filesystem>

// All hard-coded values taken directly from latest PE/COFF .docx Documentation from MS:
// => http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=84140

const int MAGIC_32_NUM = 0x10b;
const int MAGIC_64_NUM = 0x20b;

// These two require C++17 || If needed, replace with older valid file-verification.
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;
bool verify_loaded_file(std::string);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::string image_to_load;
    if (argc == 2) {
        image_to_load = argv[1];
    }
    else {
        printf("A valid path to a loadable image needs to be your only command-line parameter for %s", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }

    bool validFile = verify_loaded_file(image_to_load);

    if (!validFile) {
        printf("A valid file path of a DLL or EXE needs to be your only command-line parameter for %s", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }

    auto filesystem_image                   = fs::absolute(fs::path(image_to_load));
    std::string image_directory             = filesystem_image.parent_path().string();
    std::string image_name                  = filesystem_image.stem().string();
    std::string image_name_and_extension    = image_name + filesystem_image.extension().string();
    bool is64bit, is32bit                   = false;

    // To use MapAndLoad, you need to manually include Imagehlp.lib in your project.
    // The Imagehlp.h header alone does not suffice.
    LOADED_IMAGE loaded_image = { 0 };
    LOADED_IMAGE * p_loaded_image = &loaded_image;
    bool image_loaded = MapAndLoad(image_name_and_extension.c_str(), image_directory.c_str(), p_loaded_image, FALSE, TRUE);
    int error_check = GetLastError();

    if (!image_loaded) {
        printf("Something went wrong when trying to load %s0 with error code %s1", image_to_load.c_str(), error_check);
        UnMapAndLoad(p_loaded_image);
        return -1;
    }   

    int magic_number = loaded_image.FileHeader->OptionalHeader.Magic;

    if      (magic_number == MAGIC_32_NUM) { is32bit = true; }
    else if (magic_number == MAGIC_64_NUM) { is64bit = true; }
    else {
        printf("The magic number from the optional header wasn't detected as 32-bit or 64-bit\n");
        printf("Check Windows System Error Code: %s\n", magic_number);
        UnMapAndLoad(p_loaded_image);
        return -1;
    }

    // Skip to here
    UCHAR * module_base_address = p_loaded_image->MappedAddress;
    size_t coverted_base_address = size_t(module_base_address);

    size_t windows_optional_header_offset;
    if (is64bit) { windows_optional_header_offset = size_t(24); }
    else { windows_optional_header_offset = size_t(28); }

    size_t data_directory_optional_header_offset;
    if (is64bit) { data_directory_optional_header_offset = size_t(112); }
    else { data_directory_optional_header_offset = size_t(96); }

    size_t size_stack_commit_offset;
    if (is64bit) { size_stack_commit_offset = size_t(80); }
    else { size_stack_commit_offset = size_t(76); }

    // The commented out line below breaks with Access Violations, as does the line following it:
    // auto sum_for_size_stack = size_t(coverted_base_address + size_stack_commit_offset);
    auto sum_for_size_stack = size_t(coverted_base_address + 
                                    windows_optional_header_offset + 
                                    data_directory_optional_header_offset + 
                                    size_stack_commit_offset);

    auto direct_access_size_stack = p_loaded_image->FileHeader->OptionalHeader.SizeOfStackCommit;
    DWORD64 * addy = &direct_access_size_stack;

    printf("Direct: %s\n", direct_access_size_stack);
    printf("Pointer-Math: %s\n", sum_for_size_stack);

    UnMapAndLoad(p_loaded_image);
    return 0;
}

//

bool verify_loaded_file(std::string file_to_verify)
{
    if (fs::exists(file_to_verify))
    {
        size_t extension_query = file_to_verify.find(".dll", 0);
        if (extension_query == std::string::npos)
        {
            extension_query = file_to_verify.find(".DLL", 0);
            if (extension_query == std::string::npos)
            {
                extension_query = file_to_verify.find(".exe", 0);
                if (extension_query == std::string::npos)
                {
                    extension_query = file_to_verify.find(".EXE", 0);
                }
                else { return true; }

                if (extension_query != std::string::npos) { return true; }
            }
            else { return true; }
        }
        else { return true; }   
    }
    return false;
}
```

The PE File Format for windows has its latest documentation here in a whitepaper attachment which holds its `.docx`: http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/system/platform/firmware/PECOFF.mspx

#### Update 1:

I've got my pure pointer-arithmetic traversal working for up until just before my end-goal. Getting to that point required me to remove two layers of complexity.

1. Don't screw around with loading the image with special APIs, as I'm trying to get the *static* import information; solution for that was to load the EXE into a char vector to snapshot it in memory.
2. Forget the over-complicated sounding RVA crap unless you *need* to use it. Just use Byte Offsets for the header parts of the PE. The *sections* are where you need to use your RVA. Just consider the address of element 0 for the char vector to be your base address, for which all RVAs are calculated off from. The docx also tells you when to use the offset versus the actual address, which is good to know. Check my added answer where I briefly talk about using the RVA to get the import table.

My program still isn't doing what I want it to, but at least I have the gist of pointer-arithmetic matching the pointer accessors, which was the goal of this question.

I think my remaining blockers are related to which structures to load with data, and where. You can build and run [my WIP gist](https://gist.github.com/the-nose-knows/357c850be02e72d5651e3bada807182b) on a Win10 box, or update the value of `ph_file` to be some other locally installed 64-bit program on your OS, preferably one without an `.idata` section. The `.idata` section isn't guaranteed to exist even if importing DLLs. Calculator.exe doesn't have it, as one example.

#### Update 2:

I got some debugging help and finally got this working. The code is POC, so not much of anything is cleaned up or optimized, but it is functional. Tested against x86/win32 and x64 binaries. [Gist here](https://gist.github.com/the-nose-knows/357c850be02e72d5651e3bada807182b).

Comment: When you stepped through your debugger on the commented out line did you check to see what values were assigned to the `size_t` variables: `coverted_base_address` and `size_stack_commit_offset` to see if you are getting that values that you should be expecting? The same can be said about the next line of code.

Comment: As long as you #include Windows.h, you might as well use it to solve your problem.  CreateToolhelp32Snapshot() + Module32First/Next().  Emphasis on "snapshot", without one it is never safe.

Comment: Holy Macaroni, @HansPassant! `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` sounds great! Is that effectively a programmatically-triggered crash-dump, or even better/more information? I wish I knew about that sooner...

Comment: @FrancisCugler I don't think I'm getting the values that I was expecting. Using the `converted_base_address`, and adding the series of offsets doesn't add up to the address of the value of the `SizeOfStackCommit`. Adding only the `size_stack_commit_offset` to the `converted_base_address` doesn't either, thus my pointer-math predicament. I dumped the end-of-run variables in a gist: https://gist.github.com/the-nose-knows/b08a188665c3fd3d78d04a0ec6ce89c0. I did add another line for testing purposes, `DWORD64 * addy = &direct_access_size_stack;`

Comment: I added `auto` vars to grab all parts of `p_loaded_image` and dumped them into a gist as well. This should help shed some light on possible cross-reference/offset issues: https://gist.github.com/the-nose-knows/11dcdc481a8196a931c710b7ad160f9c

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck: You're assuming that `FileHeader` is placed at the beginning of the mapped section (0x000001560cd90000), but it isn't.  The DOS stub is placed there, and within that header is the relative location (0x000001560cd90100) of `FileHeader`.

Comment: And your variable `addy` means nothing, it's the address of a local variable containing a copy of your data.  You wanted `&p_loaded_image->FileHeader->OptionalHeader.SizeOfStackCommit`

Comment: I believe that your `windows_optional_header_offset` is wrong.  It shouldn't be MORE for 32-bit than 64-bit, and I think it's actually a constant that doesn't depend on architecture.  Looking at the structure definition, I think you have 4x2byte variables and 3x4byte variables for a total of `windows_optional_header_offset=20`.

Comment: It looks like the offset for 32-bit is greater than 64-bit, but the size for 64-bit is doubled, according to the latest documentation: http://i.imgur.com/OjDfs1q.png

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck: That's the offset from the beginning of `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER` to the `ImageBase` field.  It has nothing to do with finding the beginning of the optional header.

Comment: I don't see an offset listed for the Optional Header itself in section `3.4 Optional Header (Image Only)` -- is there some way not mentioned in this screenshot on how to get that? http://i.imgur.com/xzzvnq3.png

Comment: Thanks guys for all your help!!! As soon as I switched to loading the EXE in a vector instead of loading it, pointing to disk, and parsing what's on disk from that address, it became a lot easier to follow the documentation for the VA and RVA. Jumping into `winnt.h` didn't hurt either!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe you that the line indicated (computation of `sum_for_size_stack`) causes an access violation.  It's just unsigned arithmetic, which cannot overflow or result in a trap value.

I do believe that you get an access violation from `printf`, because you're using the `%s` format specifier with an argument that is not a pointer to a NUL-terminated ASCII string.  I have no idea what gave you the idea that stack sizes are stored as strings, or that it's a good idea to pass `size_t` to a variadic function that requires `const char*`, but neither is true.

Pay attention to the preconditions of `printf`.  The correct format string for a `size_t` parameter is `%zx`.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your insight and experience to help me understand the access violation issue! IIRC, I was converting `size_t`s like this before using `printf`, `char* converted_ptr = (char*)a_size_t_value;`, and forgot to re-add that part and use the converted value instead of the `size_t` :( I didn't understand _why_ it was a problem until you pointed it out ^_^

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck: Well, that passes the argument correctly to be retrieved as a pointer, but `printf` not only need to be able to read a `const char*` from its argument list, the pointer has to point at a NUL-terminated ASCII string, which yours does not.  Print the `size_t` value (using `%zx`) or the pointer value (using `%p`), before worrying about the value stored at the indicated memory location.

Comment: Ah, I see! While that might have sufficed to get the DLL names, other fields in the loaded pe image are clearly not all NULL-terminated ASCII strings! :( Thank you again! I've taken your advice and I've updated my actual WIP for several other `printf` issues that were less critical.

Answer (score 0):

Giving Ben credit for this one, as even though it didn't unblock me, he pointed me down the right direction when he identified my lack of understanding for pointers in correlation to memory allocation and pointer initialization from address instead of object. To overcome that, I did some studying and exercises in order to:

1. Understand how C/C++ Pointers *and* structs work in memory, also in regards to member locations in structs via byte offsets
2. Use the correct pointers to load data correctly

Doing those two things unblocked the path for pure pointer-arithmetic usage.

My problem in those regards is that I only ever needed the most basic understanding of pointers when using them in the past. This process required actually understanding memory allocation and traversal.

Overall, it's been a great re-learning experience!

At a certain point, the data accessed via a char array to load the file requires the usage of the RVA. In order to get that, you need to get the correct `IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER` struct loaded up that has your desired data. You use that struct to compute RVA with something like this to get say, the import table:

```
if  (queried_section_header->PointerToRawData >= import_table_data_dir->VirtualAddress &&
    (queried_section_header->PointerToRawData < (import_table_data_dir->VirtualAddress + queried_section_header->SizeOfRawData)))
{
    DWORD import_table_offset = queried_section_header->PointerToRawData - import_table_data_dir->VirtualAddress + queried_section_header->PointerToRawData;
}
```

I haven't personally used this guide for understanding pointers, but at a glance it looks pretty promising: http://home.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/pointers.htm 
In case it expires, this snapshot might still be around: https://web.archive.org/web/20161208002919/http://home.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/pointers.htm